# URLConnection.getInputStream() uses too much memory

Tags: java, http, download, inputstream, urlconnection

I am required to download a lot (maybe >5000) of relatively small (less than kilobyte) files on an embedded system, so I do not have too much memory.

I have written this code, it is used to download each individual file (given just one for example)

```
final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 64 * 1024;

URL fileUrl = new URL("http://10.10.0.119:8080/files/a.txt");
File fileToSave = new File("/Users/me/foo/a.txt");

URLConnection connection = fileUrl.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

InputStream us = connection.getInputStream(); // HOT SPOT (1)

try (BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(us, (int) Math.min(fileSize, 8192))) // HOT SPOT (2)
{
    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave))
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = bs.read(data, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1)
            fs.write(data, 0, c);
    }
}
```

Also mention that

```
private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 64 * 1024;
private final byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH]
```

Are allocated once per 'downloader' instance, e.g. once in lifetime.

So, I noticed, that this code uses relatively high (>200Mb) amount of memory (but all this get successfully freed by the GC further) and I started profiling using my JProfiler. What did I noticed is `connection.getInputStream()` allocates around 120Mb during my programm's lifetime, as well as allocating `BufferedInputStream` (which I have optimized by reducing its size by putting the exact size into stream constructor).

Here is my profiling results. I enabled gathering information about GCed objects. As you may notice, two heaviest hot spots are `URLConnection.getInputStream()` and `new BufferedInputStream()`, which I've mentioned.
[image]

How can I reduce memory usage under that circumstances? Maybe there's some other solutions such as:

- Reusing such streams
- Explicitly pointing the size
- Using some different approaches

Many thanks.

Comment: the code looks fine. Where have you defined data and BUFFER_LENGTH? Even if the whole file is kept in memory it is less than a KB. so 120MB is impossible. Are you calling this piece of code in a loop, once each for 5K files? Just wanting to know the meaning of program's lifetime.

Comment: @gagansingh BUFFER_LENGTH is 64Kb, I've added it into my code, thanks. And yes, the method is being called for each individual file since I do not have any Ideas to reuse such streams, connections, etc.

Comment: if you are running this code in a loop, then I would worry too much about the memory usage as long as GC is working fine. Just try running the java process with -Xmx128m. It should run fine. GC will be more frequent. Java coders are a bit more liberal with memory usage :)

Comment: Reduce `BUFFER_LENGTH`. A realistic path MTU is less than 1500 bytes. You don't need 64K bytes here. But you need to be aware that `HttpURLConnection` may buffer the entire response, and you can only control that from the other end, by using fixed-length or chunked streaming mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is reading and writing using a byte array as a buffer.  This *could* be allocated once and re-used for all of the files.  (In fact, you are probably doing that already ... though you haven't shown us the actual code.)

If you read and write using a large `byte[]` as a buffer (as you are currently doing), then there is no need to use `BufferedInputStream`.  (Using `BufferedInputStream` won't improve performance relative to using a buffer explicitly.)  And since each time you create a new `BufferedInputStream` it is allocating a new byte array as the internal buffer, you will find that reading directly from the `InputStream` (i.e. `us`) should save memory, and not cost you any performance.

---

Your ideas were:

> Reusing such streams

You can't do that with the standard Java APIs.

> Explicitly pointing the size

I assume that you mean creating buffers whose size exactly match the size of the input streams's content.

1. That won't help if you recycle the buffer (as I suggested)
2. It probably wouldn't help anyway.  At the base level, your code will be reading from a socket stream, and the reads typically won't fill the buffer anyway.  (Reading from a socket will deliver the data that is currently available in the local TCP protocol stack .... not the entire stream content ... in one `read` call`.)
3. Beyond a few Kbytes, increasing the buffer size has little performance benefit.   (Your existing 64 KB buffer size is probably not helping throughput.)

Comment: Sad, but true. I threw BufferedInputStream away and tuned my -Xmx to reduce the maximum amount of memory can be used by my program. By the way it fits 30Mb with little gc spikes, which is totally acceptable. Many thanks for your advices.